# Is there public key initialization API with point compression?

Tags: crypto++, ecdsa

I am tumbling around with CryptoPP and cannot find answer to this specific question. Here is sample source code (partial)

```
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

//Generate a private key
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
privateKey.Initialize(prng, CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1());

// Generate publicKey
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

// Extract Component values
Integer p   = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().GetField().GetModulus();
Integer a   = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().GetA();
Integer b   = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().GetB();
Integer Gx  = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetSubgroupGenerator().x;
Integer Gy  = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetSubgroupGenerator().y;
Integer n   = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetSubgroupOrder();
Integer h   = privateKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCofactor();
Integer Qx  = publicKey.GetPublicElement().x;
Integer Qy  = publicKey.GetPublicElement().y;
Integer x   = privateKey.GetPrivateExponent();

// Construct Point elelemt;
ECP curve(p,a,b);
ECP::Point G(Gx,Gy);
ECP::Point Q(Qx,Qy);

//Build publicKey using elements (no point compression)
ECDSA<ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::PublicKey GeneratedPublicKey;
GeneratedPublicKey.Initialize(curve,G,n,Q);
assert(GeneratedPublicKey.Validate(prng, 3));

//Build publicKey using elements (with point compression)?
```

With this way, I can generate publicKey using component values. However, I cannot
make it work with point compression-which means I don't have Qy value- Is there a 
way to do it? Initialize method has two overloading but none of them are for point
compression situation.

My question is specific with Crypto++ on "PublicKey.Initialize(curve,G,n,Q)". Since I cannot transfer whole publicKey with my current project-which I am force to specify domain
parameter as index value and can only transfer Qx value. So I should initialize publicKey
using something like "PublicKey.Initialize(curve,G,n,Q)" However, I cannot find such initialization API concerning point compression.

So, this is not about "how to do a point compression" but "Is there a way to initialize
public key without having Qy value?"

Comment: Tell us precisely what you have. You have never told the parameters you are using at `//Build publicKey using elements (with point compression)?`. If its an ASN.1 encoded values, show it to us in with `dumpasn1`. If the raw form is binary, the show it to us hex encoded.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Construct ECDSA publicKey using only with x value (Point compression)?

`x` is the private exponent. The public key is a point on the curve; and it does not use the private exponent.

To get the public key: take the private exponent, and raise your base point to it. That is, `Q = G^x`.

If you want to set the private exponent on a private key or decryptor, then set the domain parameters (i.e., `DL_GroupParameters_EC< ECP >` or `DL_GroupParameters_EC< EC2M >`) and then call `SetPrivateExponent(x);`.

---

Have you reviewed your previous question at [How can I recover compressed y value from sender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781563/crypto-ecsda-compressed-key-how-can-i-recover-compressed-y-value-from-other-e)? The community took the time to provide you with an answer and sample code, but you did not acknowledge or follow up.

I think [owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead) said it best [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734616/rsa-encryption-and-decryption):

> Why would we care answer you if you are not inclined to accept answers
>   or even follow up to them? Your questions are all right, but the way
>   you treat the community is terrible.

Comment: I did read your answer on my previous one and it helped me a lot. Thank you again :)

Comment: My apologies if this question looks like that I am ignoring your answer to my previous question. It is not, I did learn a lot from your previous answer and now I can do point compression. This is different question to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a way to initialize public key without having Qy value?"

Yes, there is. Here is an crypto++ example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/ecp.h>
#include <cryptopp/eccrypto.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
#include <cryptopp/oids.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() 
{
    OID curve = ASN1::secp256r1();
    ECDH<ECP>::Domain domain(curve);  

    SecByteBlock privKey(domain.PrivateKeyLength());
    SecByteBlock pubKey(domain.PublicKeyLength());
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    domain.GenerateKeyPair(prng, privKey, pubKey); 

    // Convert public key to string representation
    std::string pub_str;
    HexEncoder encoder;
    encoder.Attach( new StringSink(pub_str) );
    encoder.Put( pubKey.data(), pubKey.size() );
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    // Uncompressed point - first byte '04' in front of the string. 
    std::cout << "Uncompressed public key (point) " << pub_str << endl;

    // Extract x value from the point  
    std::string public_point_x = pub_str.substr(2, 64);

    // Compressed - '02' byte in front of the string. 
    public_point_x = "02" + public_point_x;
    std::cout << "Compressed public key (point)   " << public_point_x << endl;

    // ----- reconstruct point from compressed point/value.
    StringSource ss(public_point_x, true, new HexDecoder);   
    ECP::Point point;
    domain.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().DecodePoint(point, ss, ss.MaxRetrievable());

    cout << "Result after decompression X: " << std::hex << point.x << endl;
    cout << "Result after decompression Y: " << std::hex << point.y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this is the answer to your question. I was using ECDH, but it should work equally well with ECDSA class.